# Caracterization of strongly convex

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

A differentiable $f$ function is stronglyconvex if and only if $$f(t x_1+ (1-t) x_2) \le t f(x_1) + (1-t) f(x_2) - \frac{t (1-t)m}{2}\Vert x_1-x_2\rVert^2,~t \in [0,1] \quad(1)$$

Other characterization is that is strongly convex if and only if

\begin{equation}
g(x) = f(x)-\frac{m}{2}\lVert x \rVert^2~\text{is convex},~\forall x\quad(2)
\end{equation}

So I want to prove that (1)$\Longleftrightarrow$(2). My try is to prove when $g$ is convex what happens, so applying the definition of convexity I obtain this
\begin{align*}
  f(t x_1+ (1-t) x_2) -& \frac{m}{2} \parallel t x_1+ (1-t) x_2\parallel^2 \\&=  g(t x_1+ (1-t) x_2) \\&\le t g(x_1) + (1-t) g(x_2) \\&= t f(x_1) - \frac{m}{2} t\parallel x_1\parallel^2 + (1-t) f(x_2) - \frac{m}{2} (1-t)\parallel x_2\parallel^2, ~\forall x_2,x_1, t\in [0,1].
\end{align*}

But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Shouldn't the second characterization be for strongly convex and strict convexity doesn't imply the condition right? See http://www.princeton.edu/~amirali/Public/Teaching/ORF523/S16/ORF523_S16_Lec7_gh.pdf

Comment: It was a mistake I meant at every moment strongly convex.

Comment: makes sense now (y)

Comment: And one more thing, the 'm's are not necessarily same.

Comment: I'm not sure about that where I see that I thought it was the same. It supposed that it was the constant of strongly convex and it remains valid for every characterization.

Comment: take this $ \frac{m}{2} \parallel t x_1+ (1-t) x_2\parallel^2 $ to RHS and expand, and yes the m remains same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: take $ \frac{m}{2} \parallel t x_1+ (1-t) x_2\parallel^2 $ to RHS and expand $\parallel t x_1+ (1-t) x_2\parallel^2 $, as Euclidean norm and re-combine terms.

Expanding $\parallel t x_1+ (1-t) x_2\parallel^2 $ and combining with left out terms on right hand side $-t\parallel x_1 \parallel^2 - (1-t)\parallel x_2 \parallel^2$, we leave the terms $tf(x_1)$ and $(1-t)f(x_2)$ as they same as in (1).

$\parallel t x_1+ (1-t) x_2\parallel^2 -t\parallel x_1 \parallel^2 - (1-t)\parallel x_2 \parallel^2 $

$= t^2\parallel x_1\parallel^2 + (1-t)^2\parallel x_2\parallel^2 + t(1-t)(x_1^T x_2 + x_2^T x_1) -t\parallel x_1 \parallel^2 - (1-t)\parallel x_2 \parallel^2$

$= t(t-1)\parallel x_1\parallel^2 + t(t-1)\parallel x_2\parallel^2 + t(1-t)(x_1^T x_2 + x_2^T x_1) $

taking $t(1-t)$ common we have,

$= t(1-t)[ - \parallel x_1\parallel^2 - \parallel x_2\parallel^2 + x_1^T x_2 + x_2^T x_1]$

$= -t(1-t)\parallel x_1 - x_2\parallel^2$

combining with earlier $\frac{m}{2}$, we have

$ -\frac{m}{2} t(1-t)\parallel x_1 - x_2\parallel^2 $ we which want we want in (1). Now we do the same steps backwards we can go from (1) to (2) as well, so (1) is equivalent to (2).

Comment: Yes, this was what I tried, but they remain $(t^2 - t)\parallel x_1\parallel + ((1-t)^2-(1-t))\parallel x_2\parallel^2 + 2t(1-t)x_1^Tx_2 what it wasn't made me a lot of sense. I think I'm not expanding o recombining it the good way.

Comment: Ohk I ll expand my answer!

Comment: Ok thank you very much. What I was not seeing is about how recombine the terms. I was expanding so much.

Comment: Thanks to you as well, I could learn about strongly convex!